# unable to export multiple gridview to multiple excel

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, openxml

I am trying to export several gridviews to several excel sheets in one workbook , i have looked at many examples but havent found one that quite works. i am getting data from a stored procedure that has over 4000 records. i would to display the data on separate gridviews and then use a button to export it all to one workbook

when i try to test it i get the following at **sda.Fill(ds);** :

> An exception of type 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException' occurred in System.Data.dll but was not handled in user code
>
> Additional information: Execution Timeout Expired.  The timeout period
>   elapsed prior to completion of the operation or the server is not
>   responding.

here is my code:

```
using OfficeOpenXml;
using System.Configuration;
using DocumentFormat.OpenXml;
using ClosedXML;


 string strConnString = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["PostbankConnectionString"].ConnectionString;

protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(strConnString);

    SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("spTest", con) { CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure };

    SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter();

    command.CommandTimeout = 300;


    command.Connection = con;
    sda.SelectCommand = command;

    DataSet ds = new DataSet();

    sda = new SqlDataAdapter("spTest", con);

    sda.Fill(ds);
    GridView1.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];
    GridView1.DataBind();
    GridView2.DataSource = ds.Tables[1];
    GridView2.DataBind();
    GridView3.DataSource = ds.Tables[2];
    GridView3.DataBind();
    GridView4.DataSource = ds.Tables[3];
    GridView4.DataBind();
    GridView5.DataSource = ds.Tables[4];
    GridView5.DataBind();
    con.Close();


}
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{


    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(strConnString);

    SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("spTest", con) { CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure };

    SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter();


    command.Connection = con;
    sda.SelectCommand = command;

    DataSet ds = new DataSet();

    sda = new SqlDataAdapter("spTest", con);


    sda.Fill(ds);
    if (ds.Tables.Count > 0)
    {
        MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();

        using (ExcelPackage package = new ExcelPackage(ms))
        {
            foreach (DataTable table in ds.Tables)
            {
                ExcelWorksheet worksheet = package.Workbook.Worksheets.Add("Sheet" + i++);
                worksheet.Cells["A1"].LoadFromDataTable(table, true);
            }
            Response.Clear();
            package.SaveAs(Response.OutputStream);
            Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachchment; filename=Example.xlxs");
            Response.Charset = "";
            Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.xls";
            Response.End();
        }
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried setting command.CommandTimeout = 300 on Button1_Click event as well as I'm not able to see it in your code here or the error that you're getting is on Page_Load event itself? Try increasing the timeout also to 600 and see if it works

---

If none of the above things works, what you can try as of now is change your sp a little bit by adding where clause such that instead of 4000 rows, it gives only 10 rows or something and then execute your code. In that way,if it executes properly, then atleast you can be assured that you are getting exception due to more number of rows returned. 
But if you still face the same issue by doing this, then maybe there's something wrong in establishing the connection or something.

Comment: i added command.CommandTimeout = 600 on Button1_Click event but it still times out on the Page_Load event at sda.fill(ds)

Comment: In how much time does your stored procedure executes when you run it from sql server itself by exec spTest?

Comment: it took 8 seconds

Comment: Hmmm strange.                                                                                
`SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["PostbankConnectionString"].ConnectionString);
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("spTest", con);
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            con.Open();
            SqlDataAdapter dataAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
            var dataSet = new DataSet();
            dataAdapter.Fill(dataSet);` Try this.

Comment: Sorry for the poor indentation

Comment: i get the same error at  dataAdapter.Fill(dataSet); on page load

Comment: i changed my code to only fill one gridview with and it shows the data however when i click on the button to export to excel it it timesout at page load `sda.Fill(ds);` it doesn't even get to `protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)`

Comment: I'm a little bit unaware of the Page LifeCycle in this case as I've always worked in MVC. Correct me where I go wrong: 1. When you run your application, your Page_Load method gets called and from there, you're calling your SP and returning the data to UI. 2. There's a button in your UI which on clicking calls your Button1_Click method and which is again calling your SP and exporting the data fetched to excel. If that's the case, then in your above mentioned comment, you told that you're able to show the data on UI on changing your SP, then how come it is throwing exception at Page_Load method?

Comment: yes thats how it works, the data then displays on gridview but does not export to excel it just timesout

Comment: So when you changed your SP to give less data, now the Page_Load method is not giving that exception at`sda.Fill(ds)` but on Button1_Click method, it's giving you that exception at `sda.Fill(ds)` itself eventhough both the methods are calling that same SP... If that's the case, then it's a little bit weird as your code is same in both the cases. Make sure to open the connection at Button1_Click method also `con.Open();`...  Also add try catch in your block to see the exceptions in full details..